# Dropping a term in a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, approximation

In high-energy electron diffraction calculations, it is common practice to make a small-angle or "paraxial" approximation, which involves dropping a second-order derivative term in the governing equation for the system. Assuming we have an electron plane wave in $z$ incident upon a specimen potential $U(\textbf{r})$, we start from the Schrödinger equation:

$$ \{\nabla^2 + 4\pi^2 [U(\textbf{r}) + K^2]\}\Psi(\textbf{r}) = 0$$

And assume the wave can be described as a modulated plane wave:

$$ \Psi(\textbf{r}) = \exp(2\pi i K z) \Phi(\textbf{r}) $$

This yields

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi(\textbf{r})}{\partial z^2} + 4\pi i K \frac{\partial \Phi(\textbf{r})}{\partial z} + \Delta \Phi(\textbf{r}) + 4\pi^2 U(\textbf{r})\Phi(\textbf{r}) = 0$$

where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in $x$ and $y$.
At this point we argue that the second-order derivative in $z$ is small relative to the other terms, because most of the variation of $\Psi$ in $z$ is described by the $\exp(2\pi i K z)$ factor. So we discard that term and we're left with:

$$ 4\pi i K \frac{\partial \Phi(\textbf{r})}{\partial z} + \Delta \Phi(\textbf{r}) + 4\pi^2 U(\textbf{r})\Phi(\textbf{r}) = 0$$

My question is essentially about whether it is "proper" to just drop a derivative term like this. More specifically:

1. Even if the dropped term is indeed small, it seems like it drastically alters the "character" of the differential equation. The order in $z$ has changed, the boundary conditions required to specify the solution are *qualitatively* different, and the solution method is much more straightforward (we can solve plane-by-plane in $z$). Is this really a valid way to solve the original differential equation?
2. If this is indeed a "dodgy" mathematical procedure, is there a better way to make the approximation? And how can we understand why the "dodgy" procedure seems to give the (approximately) right answer? I assume some kind of series expansion could be made but I'm not sure how or where to do it.
3. Is there some branch or theorem of mathematics that I can refer to to understand more about this type of problem? It's been a number of years since I studied calculus so I've forgotten how to think rigorously about these problems.

Comment: Do you conclude that $\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z} = 0$ from the last equation (which allows you to treat $z$ parametrically when solving for $\Phi$?  If so, it would be that conclusion that allows you to neglect the second $z$ derivative.

Comment: uhh just realised what I said doesn't make sense, I will have a second think.